Why .NET MAUI Grid is not extending vertically
I'm trying to add a Welcome Screen for my App, it consists out of a title label, 2 buttons lined in stack vertically and a frame which would hold recently edited files. Elements are added to grid but for some reason Grid takes only about 50% of available vertical space.
XAML markdown for the UI:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BXMT.MainPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                Text="Title Label" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,20,0,20"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" />
            <Frame Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                BorderColor="LightGray" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="20">
            </Frame>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                Padding="30" Spacing="20"
                Margin="40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="Button 1" />
                <Button Text="Button 2" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>

How the Grid ends up looking in Dynamic Preview:

I tried explicitly setting Grid's VerticalOptions to FillAndExpand but it didn't gave any positive results

Remove it from VerticalStackLayout and it will

After my testing, the VerticalStackLayout in the code conflicts with the layout of the Grid.
You can remove the <VerticalStackLayout> and adjust the Rowdefinitions and columndefinitions of the Grid to achieve the desired layout:
<Grid ...>
    <Gird.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Gird.RowDefinitions>
...

